# How to filter sign-ins and get a specific user's authentication requirement by using Microsoft graphs and PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, api, microsoft-graph-api, multi-factor-authentication

How to filter sign-ins and get a specific user's authentication requirement by using Microsoft graphs and PowerShell?

e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you call it in Microsoft Graph Explorer, use this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=userPrincipalName eq '{user Principal Name}'
```

**UPDATE:**

In Powershell, use this:

```
$graphToken = token
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?`$filter=userPrincipalName eq '{user Principal Name}'"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($graphToken)" }  -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Debug
$result.value
```